# error after startup of Ionic app uncaught by crashlytics fabric

Tags: ionic-framework

I am facing error during init of ionic app on mobile device.

https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/1182

The error is not caught by fabric crashlytics. As an app integrated with fabric is able to detect new release despite the error (on start when new build is available there is popup allowing to install new version) I wonder that it should be also able to register the error/crash while in fact particular broken release is not even registered as executed (it's only shown as installed) in fabric dashboard.

Is there an option to report an issue? Or maybe it is possible to tweak the integration so the errors during initialization will be captured?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Crashlytics doesn't have Ionic support so it wouldn't surprise me if there are crashes we're not capturing correctly.

Comment: There is support actually, even if not directly from Fabric - https://github.com/sarriaroman/FabricPlugin - and I am using it successfully and able to catch other crashes.

Comment: just in case anyone may find this useful - here is bug report https://github.com/sarriaroman/FabricPlugin/issues/142